# Node Express custom 404 page

Tags: node.js, express

I have a pretty standard Node Express app with a global 404 handler like.

```
app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.status(404);
    res.render('404page');
});
```

Now in some routes I have code like

```
app.get('/store/:product', function (req, res) {
  if (productNotFound) return res.sendStatus(404);
});
```

What I would like is the res.sendStatus(404) to redirect to the error page WITHOUT having to change it to res.sendStatus(404).render('404page').

Is that possible?

Comment: Use res.redirect(“route”)

Comment: This code can't change
if (productNotFound) return res.sendStatus(404);

Comment: Can you explain more what you want exactly?

Comment: I want to intercept the 404 at a global level and redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Just override `.sendStatus` of `res` object.

Register this middleware right after creating the express app:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const sendStatus = res.sendStatus.bind(res);
  res.sendStatus = (status) => {
    if (status === 404) {
      return res.status(404).render('404page');
    }
    return sendStatus(status);
  }
  next()
});
```